# python functionality to parse a csv file containing tables

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to read and process in python.

The CSV file contains tabular values as follows:

```
*aa
1    foo1    foo_bar1 
2    foo2    foo_bar2
*bb
1.22    bla1    blabla1    blablabla22
1.33    bla2    ' '        blablabla33
```

Here `aa` and `bb` are the names of each table. Wherever table names occur, the name is preceded by a * and the rows below it are the rows of that table.

Note that each table can have:

1. different number of columns as well as rows.
2. There can also be empty columns representing missing values. I would like to keep them as ' ' after reading in.

However, we know exactly which tables are present in the csv file (i.e. the table names)

I need to read in the csv file and assign a table's entire content to one variable. I can think of a brute force way of doing this. However, since python has a csv module with read write operations, is there any built in functionality that could make this easier or more efficient for me?

Note: One of the major problem I've faced so far is that after reading in the csv file using `csv.reader()`, I see that aa's rows have additional empty columns. I believe this is because of the mismatch in the number of aa's and bb's columns. I also want to get rid of these additional empty columns without deleting the empty columns that represent actual missing values.

Comment: (1) Are you allowed to add another line to the top of the file? (2) Do you know the maximal number of columns?

Comment: (1) No. We cannot add anything to the file before reading it. But if we could, I'm curious to know how it makes a difference.

(2) Yes. The max number of columns is known.

Comment: Let's say you have at most N columns. I would add a line of N space-separated symbols (say, 1's) at the top of the file and use Pandas: `pd.read_csv('foo.csv',sep=r'\s+',error_bad_lines=False)`. It works on the example that you posted.

Comment: Those look like lists not tables. Where are the column names?

Comment: Column of the tables have names but they are not explicitly mentioned in the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse your csv file like so checking if the first value startswith a `'*'` and build a `dict` from it.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

csv_data = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    # filter empty lines
    csv_reader = csv.reader(filter(lambda l: l.strip(',\n'), csv_file))

    header = None
    for row in csv_reader:
        if row[0].startswith('*'):
            header = row[0]
        else:
            # additional row processing if needed
            csv_data[header].append(row)

pprint.pprint(csv_data)

# Output
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'*aa': [['1', ' foo1', 'foo_bar1', ''],
                     ['2', ' foo2', 'foo_bar2', '']],
             '*bb': [['1.22', ' bla1', 'blabla1', 'blablabla22'],
                     ['1.333', ' bla2', '', 'blablabla3']]})
```

---

If you want to remove the excess elements from a table due to another being larger, one option is

```
csv_data[header].append(row[:col_nums[header]])
```

Where as you mentioned you know how many columns your table should have

```
col_nums = {'*aa' : 3, '*bb' : 4}

defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
        {'*aa': [['1', ' foo1', 'foo_bar1'], 
                 ['2', ' foo2', 'foo_bar2']],
         '*bb': [['1.22', ' bla1', 'blabla1', 'blablabla22'],
                 ['1.333', ' bla2', '', 'blablabla3']]})
```

---

If I misread it and you only know the max number of columns and not the number of columns for each table, then you could instead do.

```
def trim_row(row):
    for i, item in enumerate(reversed(row)):
        if not item:
            break
    return row[:len(row) - i]

# use it like so
csv_data[header].append(trim_row(row))
```

Comment: This would not get rid of the additional empty rows that show up in aa, correct?

Comment: Correct, you can add that to it though, I'll add it in.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to separate the tables before feeding each group to the csv reader.  Here is a rough cut to get you started:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import csv

# Instead of *s*, you can use an open file object here
s = '''\
*aa
1,foo1,foo_bar1 
2,foo2,foo_bar2
*bb
1.22,bla1,blabla1,blablabla22
1.33,bla2,       ,blablabla33
'''.splitlines()

it = iter(s)
next(it)
for table in ['aa', 'bb']:
    print(f'\nTable: {table}')
    for row in csv.reader(takewhile(lambda r: not r.startswith('*'), it)):
        print(row)
```

This produces:

```
Table: aa
['1', 'foo1', 'foo_bar1 ']
['2', 'foo2', 'foo_bar2']

Table: bb
['1.22', 'bla1', 'blabla1', 'blablabla22']
['1.33', 'bla2', '       ', 'blablabla33']
```

Comment: What does this statement do: print(f'\nTable: {table}')? What is f?

Comment: @PeshalNayak It is a Python 3.6 formatted string, a newer and nicer way of writing ``print('\nTable: {table}'.format(table=table)``.   That said, this isn't the  substantive part of the answer; rather, it is just one of many ways to print the table headings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep=r'/s+', header=None) #if there is table headings, remove header = None
```

You **do not** need to add any line to the top of the file.
This reads files with different number of rows and columns into a dataframe. You can perform all sorts of actions in it now. For ex:
Empty elements are represented by NaN, which means Not a Number. You can replace it with ' ' just by writing

```
df.fillna(' ')
```

To fit your use case, from what i understand, you have multiple tables in the same csv file, try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", header=None, names=range(3))
table_names = ["*aa", "*bb", "*cc"..]
groups = df[0].isin(table_names).cumsum()
tables = {g.iloc[0,0]: g.iloc[1:] for k,g in df.groupby(groups)}
```

This will create a list of tables with key as table name and value as the table itself.

```
for k,v in tables.items():
   print("table:", k)
   print(v)
   print()
```

You can find more details in the [documentation.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)